# Retrieve data from MySQL according to the item_ID selected from the select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a populated MySql database, my database has two columns (item_ID, item_title), and my HTML page has a select box, where all the item_IDs are stored, and below it I have a input box, now I want to do the following:
When the user selects an item_ID from the select box, it should go to the database and find out what is the item_title that belongs to that item_ID.
I am currently using PHP, I don't know how to carry such task. 
Thank you in advance.

NB: I am okay populating the select box with all the available item_IDs. The only thing I am not sure how to implement is to retrieve the item_title dynamically as the item_ID changes, and display inside input box.

```
<select name='item_ID'>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>

<input name='item_title' value='Should change as the item_ID changes' />
```

Comment: You could generate your `select` already with an attribute like `data-title` on each `option`. So will not need to request for it each time the select is changed. Got it?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I am sure you are right with that point, but I don't know how it works, a quick example will help me to better understand. Thank you

Comment: I've posted an answer, check it out.

Comment: If you want the exact behavior, you need to use AJAX along with PHP. When user selects some item, it triggers an Ajax function which transfers selected item_id to a php function. The function runs a `SELECT` query on a database to retrieve the item title for particular item_ID. Then it sends back that title to your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you generate your `select` element dinamically with PHP:

```
<?php

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($some_query)) {
        echo "<option>" + $row["id"] + "</option>";
    }

?>
```

Right? But now why not add the `title` in the same query and generate the select with it?

```
echo "<option data-title='" + $row["title"] + "'>" + $row["id"] + "</option>";
```

Nice, so your select will looks like:

```
<select name='item_ID'>
    <option data-title="Title 1">1</option>
    <option data-title="Title 2">2</option>
    <option data-title="Title 3">3</option>
    <option data-title="Title 4">4</option>
</select>
```

Now you bind a `change` event to the select like this:

```
$("#item_ID").on("change", function(e) {
    var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
    $("#item_title").val($(selectedOption).data("title"));
});
```

Don't forget to add `id="item_title"` to your title field.

So, with this approach you won't need an extra request and extra query to database in order to get the title by adding it in the same query that you use to create the `select`(with `inner/left join` if its from another table, I think). Thus, it will increase your application performance.

**UPDATE:**

The event binding should stay on the `ready` event of the `document`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#item_ID").on("change", function(e) {
        var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
        $("#item_title").val($(selectedOption).data("title"));
    });
});
```

And for more columns you just add them with `data-` prefix to the `option` element attributes:

```
<option data-title="" data-other-property=""></option>
```

And so on... Then to access it you use the same method:

```
$(selectedOption).data("title");
$(selectedOption).data("other-property");
```

Considering `selectedOption` stands for the option element.

Some references the worth a reading:

- [Using data attributes @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)
- [$(document).ready() @ jQuery Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: thank you very much, it actually makes sense now, I was just wondering where should I place that change event code, and do you know whether I can use the same approach if I have more than two columns?

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly fine, the only issue I am having now is that when the title had space in between it is throwing out the rest and keeping the first word, so if 'Smiff Off' is meant to be inside data-title, it would only keep 'Smiff', any clues?

Comment: @Jordan are you sure that you html is being printed well? I mean, the string content is printed full in the html, the javascript that is messing it ? Look [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RvGq/). It seems to work.

Comment: Yes, it was purely my lack of attention on using double and single quotes. After properly analyzing your syntax I got my head around. Thank you so much, you have been very helpful.